# android : How to work around the fact that a singleInstance activity cannot expect to rely onActivityResult when starting subActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am making an android application, which has the following execution flow:

1. A service registers a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager
2. When the alarm is launched, a `Receiver` receives the intent, and (given some conditions) calls `startsActivity()` for my `Main Activity`, which in the manifest has been declared as     `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`. Note that for this call to work, the intent passed should have an `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`
3. When started, `Main Activity` modifies itself a bit, and calls `startActivityForResult` for an Activity, which we'll call `WebviewActivity` (because it contains a webview, but that's besides the point)
4. When the user is done interacting with the`WebViewActivity`, `setResult()` and `finish()` are called on it, and one would expect for `MainActivity.onActivityResult()` to be called.

But of course this does not happen, as has been documented in many discussions here, the reason apparently being that an Activity launched from a `singleInstance` Activity, runs in a different Task.

A solution I think would be to have the `WebActivity` start the `MainActivity` instead.

The question is, is there a way to maintain `onActivityResult` being called at the right time? In that case, which aspects from the starting point of the execution flow should change?

Please note that `MainActivity` should not have multiple instances at the same time (it is basically an interface to the service) but if its `launchMode` is set to `standard`, the Receiver, because of the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` that is required, will do just that.

Manifest declaration of `MainActivity`:

```
    <activity   android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        android:uiOptions=”splitActionBarWhenNarrow”
    </activity>
```

Receiver launches `MainActivity` by calling

```
 onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
     intent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
     int flag = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
     intent.setFlags(flag);
     context.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: In order to help you, please explain why your `MainActivity` has `launchMode="singleInstance"`. In general this is a bad idea (unless you are writing a HOME-screen replacement, which you are obviously not doing).

Comment: MainActivity is a report of the application's overall status. Also, w hen `MainActivity` receives an intent to launch the `WebActivity`, it also constructs in its layout a button to make this particular instance accessible to the user for a period of time. I thought that having a `singleInstance`  of `MainActivity` is a good way to not have to manage initializing different instances of it, or have them be in disagreement as to what they display. Do you see a different way to do that?

Comment: This is still very confusing. If your application is not started by other applications, there is no reason to use the launch modes `singleInstance` or `singleTask`. Unless your app is started by other apps, your app will always run in its own task and you can manage whether or not you want to have multiple instances of any given activity.

Comment: You wrote __ MainActivity should have multiple instances at the same time__ but you declare it as `singleInstance`. However, `singleInstance` means that there should be one and only one instance of this activity. I think you don't understand all the repercussions of using `singleInstance`.

Comment: You are right David, apologies. It was a typo. It should state _should not have multiple instances_. I have noticed that if `MainActivity` has `launchMode="standard"`, then whenever the receiver calls startActivity, a new instance of `MainActivity` is launched. The reason is that the receiver requires that FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is set

Comment: This doesn't necessarily have to create a new instance. You can use a combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` or you can just use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and launch the root activity of the task and this should NOT create a new instance. Please explain what activities are on the stack when the receiver launches it.

Comment: The activities on the stack can either be `MainActivity`, `WebActivity`, both, or none of them. Usually, it's just `MainActivity` when I'm testing though. Does this help?  Indeed FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will not create a new instance, but that's only in the singleInstance case right? Then `MainActivity.onActivityResult` will be called immediately after the call of `MainActivity.startActivityForResult( _WebActivity_)`.

Comment: If you launch your "root" activity (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) and set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, then this will simply bring an existing task containing this activity to the foreground. It will do this **no matter what the launch mode of the activity is**. If there is no existing instance of the activity, this will simply create one, which is what you want. Try that.

Comment: David, without `launchMode="singleInstance"`, the root activity is launched again, (`onCreate()` is called instead of `onNewIntent()`) and pressing the Back button on it, takes you to the previous instance.

Comment: That is broken. That should definitely NOT happen. Believe me, you do NOT want launch mode `singleInstance`. Post your manifest and the code you use to create the notification. Also, make sure that your application is launched by hand (from the HOME screen) the first time. Do not launch the app from an IDE (like Eclipse) or by pressing the "open" button on the installer screen.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following workaround for this problem:

Activity A is the caller

Activity B is the singleInstance activity from which I want the result

In activity A I register a broadcast receiver as following

```
PickReceiver receiver=new PickReceiver();
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("ActivityA_pick");
registerReceiver(receiver,filter);

class PickReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(intent.getAction().equals("ActivityA_pick")){
        //get data from intent extras
    }
}
```

In ActivityB when it's time to send the data I use:

```
sendBroadcast("ActivityA_pick").putExtra("...data...");
finish();
```

This way i can get the result I want when I want a result from one of my own activities. If you want a result from the system or another app you can adjust this using a dummy activity that doesn't have launch mode singleInstance, have it start the activity for result and when it gets it onActivityResult it sends the broadcast to the caller.

Hope this helps

Comment: This wont work if OS kills your A Activity to recover memory - enable 'do not keep activities' option in your device developer option to replicate this manually

Answer (score 0):

As the Main Activity is a single instance, is doing what it has been told.

So yes, you have to start the Main Activity from the Web Activity in order to be coherent with the tasks executions